# Google Sheets script UserForm - Send Data from Form to Spreadsheet- userform fields not handled correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, userform

I am new to google scripting. I have followed some tutorials online and created a user form which has 4 input:
company name, qty, agent and comment. The only goal here is to copy data from user form to spread sheet. I have written the following html and functions but data does not get populated after button add is clicked.

```
I know the addRowData function is working when correct input gets to it. So either I am not population rowData correctly or EventListener does not work correctly. Can anybody please help me find where the issue is?

    function addNewRow(rowData) {
  const currentDate=new Date();
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws=ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  ws.appendRow([currentDate, rowData.companyName,rowData.qty,rowData.agentName,rowData.commentText]); 
  return true;
}


   <div class="container">
      <div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company-name">Company</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number-boxes">Number of Boxes</label>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="number-boxes">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="agent-name">Agent</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agent-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment-text">Comment</label>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="comment-text">
      </div>
      <button  class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>


     <script>
       function afterButtonClicked(){
         var companyName = getElementById("company-name");
         var qty = getElementById("number-boxes");
         var agentName = getElementById("agent-name");
         var commentText = getElementById("comment-text");
         var rowData={companyName: companyName.value,qty: qty.value,agentName: agentName.value,commentText: commentText.value};
         google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData);
       }
       function afterSubmit(e){
         var qty = getElementById("number-boxes");
         qty.value="";
       }
       
       document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked());
     </script>
  
  
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification points:

- At `document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked());`, the function is run by `()` of `afterButtonClicked()` at the load of HTML. In this case, please remove `()`.
- About `getElementById("###")`, in this case, please add `document` like `document.getElementById("###")`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. I think that your Google Apps Script works.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify your Javascript as follows.

```
<script>
 function afterButtonClicked(){
   var companyName = document.getElementById("company-name");
   var qty = document.getElementById("number-boxes");
   var agentName = document.getElementById("agent-name");
   var commentText = document.getElementById("comment-text");
   var rowData={companyName: companyName.value,qty: qty.value,agentName: agentName.value,commentText: commentText.value};
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData);
 }
 function afterSubmit(e){
   var qty = document.getElementById("number-boxes");
   qty.value="";
 }
 
 document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
</script>
```

#### References:

- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: @user1372020 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.